# Error! argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable while running terraform script

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, terraform, infrastructure

I am using the terraform `Terraform v0.6.16` and I can't upgrade it, I was able to run terraform scripts earlier almost 3-4 months back but suddenly it started giving me below error.

Note that nothing is changed in the code.

Terraform command  :- `tf plan --var-file my-tf.tfvars`

Error which I get :-

> Error! argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

I know I am using the very old version of **terraform**, But Upgrading it is not a option as of now.

Also I know it's something related to `python`, I am using `Python 2.7.6` with Ubuntu 14.04.

Let me know if there is any other information required.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: What specific peice of code ? Its a prop. code and can't share..

Comment: You could strip out the sensitive parts and post it.

Comment: @KJH , I Know that, But it's not easy to do it.

Comment: Strip out Access Keys, names, IP address aka information propriety to your organization, the rest should just be the resources and how you structure your terraform code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Terraform itself does not run Python code, so this issue must be coming from some other software that you've configured Terraform to run. That could for example be a `provisioner` block, or a `data "external"` block. Once you've found the relevant code that Terraform is running, I suspect this will really be a Python question rather than a Terraform question.